# How to calculate the ratio of data in and outside of an interval in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
Frequency = 260 



[1] -9.326550e-03
   [2] -4.422175e-03
   [3]  9.003794e-03
   [4] -1.778217e-03
   [5] -4.676712e-03
   [6]  1.242704e-02
   [7]  5.759863e-03
```

And I want to count how many of these are in between these:

```
Frequency = 260 



           [,1]         [,2]
[1]         NA           NA
[2] 0.010363147 -0.010363147
[3] 0.010072569 -0.010072569
[4] 0.010018997 -0.010018997
[1] 0.009700522 -0.009700522
[5] 0.009476024 -0.009476024
[7] 0.009748085 -0.009748085
```

I have to do this in r, but I'm a beginner. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is present an R object. That output does not suggest you have yet done anything with R. It's not a typical result of a print operation. Make an object and present the needed interval breaks in R code.

Comment: They are time series objects I think

Comment: Are your ranges always symmetric about zero? In that case, comparing with absolute values would be simplest.

Comment: If they are R objects then present them with output from `dput(obj)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand -- you want the number of times the j-th element of your first object is between the two elements of the j-th row of the second?  If so,

```
sum( (data1  > data2[,1]) & (data1 < data2[,2]))/length(data1)
```

Will do it.

Comment: Hmm, I definitely read the OP question differently, I guess only they can clarify. :)

Comment: Yes, I want exactly that! Thank you!

Comment: One thing to note is that @Carl's solution won't work if your data actually do have the first range (or others) with NA values present. You'll need to add the `na.rm=T` argument to the sum: `sum( d > r[,1] & d < r[,2], na.rm=T)`

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens  Good point. Always important to do data validation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using `foverlaps` from the package `data.table`, with the following toy data sets:

```
library(data.table)
##
set.seed(123)
ts1 <- data.table(
  ts(rnorm(50, sd = .1), frequency = 260))[
    ,V2 := V1]
##
ts2 <- cbind(
  ts(rnorm(50,-0.1,.5), frequency=260)
  ,ts(rnorm(50,0.1,.5), frequency=260))
ts2 <- data.table(
  t(apply(ts2, 1, sort)))[
    1, c("V1", "V2") := NA]
setkeyv(ts2, c("V1","V2"))
```

Since `foverlaps` needs two columns from each of the input `data.table`s, we just duplicate the first column in `ts1` (this is the convention, as far as I'm aware).

```
fts <- foverlaps(
  x = ts1, y = na.omit(ts2)
  ,type = "within")[
    ,list(Freq = .N)
    ,by = "V1,V2"]
```

This joins `ts1` on `ts2` for every occurrence of a `ts1` value that falls within each of `ts2`'s `[V1, V2]` intervals - and then aggregates to get a count by interval. Since it is feasible that some of `ts2`'s intervals will contain zero `ts1` values (which is the case with this sample data), you can left join the aggregate data back on the original `ts2` object, and derive the corresponding proportions:

```
(merge(x = ts2, y = fdt, all.x=TRUE)[
  is.na(Freq), Freq := 0][
    ,Inside := Freq/nrow(ts1)][
      ,Outside := 1 - Inside])[1:10,]
##
#            V1          V2 Freq Inside Outside
# 1:         NA          NA    0   0.00    1.00
# 2: -1.2545844 -0.37373731    0   0.00    1.00
# 3: -0.9266236 -0.21024328    1   0.02    0.98
# 4: -0.8743764 -0.29245223    0   0.00    1.00
# 5: -0.7339710  0.19230687   50   1.00    0.00
# 6: -0.7103589  0.13898042   50   1.00    0.00
# 7: -0.7089414 -0.26660369    0   0.00    1.00
# 8: -0.7007681  0.58032622   50   1.00    0.00
# 9: -0.6860721  0.01936587   35   0.70    0.30
# 10: -0.6573338 -0.41395304    0   0.00    1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

I think @nrussell's answer is just fine, but you can accomplish your answer much more simply using base R, so I'll document it here for you since you said you're a beginner.  I've commented it as well to hopefully help you learn what's going on:

```
##  Set a seed so simulated data can be duplicated:
set.seed(2001)

##  Simulate your data to be counted:
d <- rnorm(50)

##  Simulate your ranges:
r <- rnorm(10)
r <- cbind(r - 0.1, r + 0.1)

##  Sum up the values of d falling inside each row of ranges.  The apply
##    function takes each row of r, and compares the values of d to the
##    bounds of your ranges (lower in the first column, upper in the second)
##    and the resulting logical vector is then summed, where TRUEs are equal
##    to 1, thus counting the number of values in d falling between each
##    set of bounds:
sums <- apply(r, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) { sum( d > x[1] & d < x[2] ) })

##  Each item of the sums vector refers to the corresponding
##      row of ranges in the r object...
```